# I can't get out of grub + you need to load the kernel first

Tags: grub2, 17.10

I started upgrading to ubuntu 17.10 from 17.04 and then for some reason I shut off the computer. When I turned it back on, it showed "GNU GRUB version 2.02~beta3-4ubuntu7". When I type in boot it says "you need to load the kernel first". "Exit" brings me to the bios and "normal" don't bring me anywhere. When I try to boot from bios i come to grub. (I boot from "ubuntu (P1: Kingston SUV400S37240G)". The other boot option is only the name of my SSD which brings me to the "boot properly blah blah"

Specs:

- mobo: Gigabyte AB350M-HD3
- CPU: Ryzen 3 1200
- GPU: GeForce gtx 1050 ti

Answer (score 5):

Try the following steps:

```
ls [to see paritions]
```

Then ls root directory of each, to find the one linux installed on. e.g:

```
ls (hd1,6)/ [let's assume linux is installed here]

linux (hd1,6)/boot/vm [===> press TAB to auto-complete] root=/dev/sda6

initrd (hd1,6)/boot/ini [===> press TAB to auto-complete]

boot
```

Hopefully! in linux:

```
sudo update-grub

grub-install /dev/sda
```

If, for any reason, you couldn't make grub work. Install Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Answer (score 0):

Your situation almost certainly indicates that the upgrade process was only partly completed, and your operating system is damaged in a way that can't be booted.  The only practical solution to this is to do a full install (of 17.10, back to 17.04, or even of 16.04 LTS).

Done with the proper choices during installation, this need not damage data stored in /home, though it certainly can -- if you have the ability to do so (say, by booting a Live media OS) you should back up any data you want to keep before proceeding.