# Hard disk has become read-only. fsck, some other solutions listed below did not work

Tags: partitioning, mount, disk, read-only

I am a new Linux user, on Ubuntu Desktop 22.04.03 LTS. For trying Linux, I started with a dual boot with windows 10 on 256GB nvme SSD and 495 GB default partition made by ubuntu for dual boot on the 1TB hard drive on my laptop(Lenovo Legion Y540). After using it for a month without issue I was confident that I could install it as my sole operating system without problems, that is where the partitioning led to an issue paired with my lack of understanding. My hard drive is stuck on read only now even after many steps followed from similar posts here.

At first, my primary mistake was not recognising the 'Erase Disk' option removed all files and partitions from the laptop only on the selected drive for install. As a result, I was left with my leftover Data partition for windows prior use and my older ubuntu install. I was able to read and write from Data at least, if I remember correctly, while I didn't check the old Ubuntu partition. I deleted the files from data, and after looking up the problem installed gparted. I couldn't extend the drive as Data was separated from the extra Ubuntu by a UEFI partition. There were 4 partitions, a leftover partition for windows use, Data, fat32 UEFI and ext4 older ubuntu install. I removed the first 3 partitions, used gparted to make the fourth partition shift to the start of the drive and take up all space, but it wouldn't allow me to use 3MB at the start of the drive. I proceeded regardless. Since then, my drive has been stuck on read only mode. I have since reinstalled my nvme main ubuntu a few times, and in the end in the hope of it getting fixed after figuring an "Erase Disk install" removes all partitions from a drive only, reinstalled using the same on the Hard drive(Starting after this paragraph, I have listed all actions in the order I performed them). That removed all partitions and set partitions for this extra Ubuntu install to use up the whole drive. But the drive is still only in read only mode. The  hard disk drive is read only when I try to write from the main nvme Ubuntu or the extra hard disk ubuntu.
I tried using the `sudo fsck` command(because running only fsck gave "permission denied"). It gave me a drive mounted error, reproduced here.

```
e2fsck 1.46.5 (30-Dec-2021)
/dev/nvme0n1p2 is mounted.



WARNING!!!  The filesystem is mounted.   If you continue you ***WILL***
cause ***SEVERE*** filesystem damage.


Do you really want to continue<n>? no
check aborted.
fsck.fat 4.2 (2021-01-31)
```

Using gparted, I unmounted the partition(and it couldn't be mounted back), called /dev/sda4 back then (my main install which replaced Windows is called /dev/nvme0n1. After that I ran `sudo fsck /dev/sda4`, which outputted some code, which cannot be reproduced exactly because this was done before I did an "Erase Disk install" on the hard drive, but it essentially gave back a result of clean. Using the same command after the new extra Ubuntu install which took the whole hard disk gave a similar result.

I then tried to do a whole disk format(slow, rewriting all to 0s). But after a few hours and with the write speed reducing from 37MB/s to 15MB/s in around 5 hours of running, I checked about it and from a few forum posts there was a consensus that cancelling it and doing a quick format did no harm. On doing so, I found the hard drive still being read-only. I then figured that the clean disk install of ubuntu removed all partitions and clears all data, and installs Ubuntu. I did it with the hope that it would fix the file system. It did install but thereafter the drive was still read-only. My partition after fresh install on hard drive was /dev/sda2. The command used for it was `sudo fsck /dev/sda2`, essentially giving the output clean. I cannot reproduce this result, the last part of this post will give the output for said command used now. Before that, the other steps used were using the `sudo fdisk -f /dev/sda2 command`. By by memory, it printed the contents of block1, block2… till block 5 and some other text. At that point I was still going trial and error with no plan of making a forum post or the foresight to save the code.

Following another guide, I loaded the extra hard drive ubuntu install in recovery mode and ran fdisk on that filesystem. It gave

```
fsck from util-linux 2.37.2
/dev/sda2 is mounted.
e2fsck: Cannot continue, aborting.

Finished, please press enter.
```

Note that this one wasn't copy-pasted and there may possibly be some issue with spacing as I typed it out.

I believed the very purpose of fsck in recovery mode was to be able to run it on a drive in use. But that did not work.

As for running the `sudo fsck /dev/sda2` command from my main SSD install now, which my hard disk install partition being unmounted already(and unable to be mounted), the output is

```
Be careful before using the write command.

The device contains 'ext4' signature and it will be removed by a write command. See fdisk(8) man page and --wipe option for more details.

Device does not contain a recognized partition table.
Created a new DOS disklabel with disk identifier 0x9ce09f40.

Command (m for help)
```

I would appreciate being able to fix this drive finally so that I can use it for basic use, and as initially intended I do not intend to mess with partitions after fixing the drive as I do not understand it. I am hoping I can get the required help here. After that, I wish to uninstall the extra Ubuntu on the hard disk, and use said disk with my sole main Ubuntu install after uninstalling the one currently on the disk. That is for later but clear steps would help in avoiding unexpected issues again.

**Edit**: I pressed m for help. That resulted in

```
  DOS (MBR)
   a   toggle a bootable flag
   b   edit nested BSD disklabel
   c   toggle the dos compatibility flag

  Generic
   d   delete a partition
   F   list free unpartitioned space
   l   list known partition types
   n   add a new partition
   p   print the partition table
   t   change a partition type
   v   verify the partition table
   i   print information about a partition

  Misc
   m   print this menu
   u   change display/entry units
   x   extra functionality (experts only)

  Script
   I   load disk layout from sfdisk script file
   O   dump disk layout to sfdisk script file

  Save & Exit
   w   write table to disk and exit
   q   quit without saving changes

  Create a new label
   g   create a new empty GPT partition table
   G   create a new empty SGI (IRIX) partition table
   o   create a new empty DOS partition table
   s   create a new empty Sun partition table


Command (m for help): i
No partition is defined yet!

Command (m for help): i /dev/sda2
No partition is defined yet!

Command (m for help): w

The partition table has been altered.
Calling ioctl() to re-read partition table.
Re-reading the partition table failed.: Invalid argument

The kernel still uses the old table. The new table will be used at the next reboot or after you run partprobe(8) or partx(8).
```

I will now reboot to see if it fixed anything.

**Edit2**: That messed everything up. I've now loaded GNU GRUB version 2.06

Using `boot` gives the following

```
error: you need to load the kernel first.
```

**Edit3**: On the basis of trial and error, looking at the relevant posts online and solutions, double checking to try to understand before acting, I tried to boot back into my laptop which I hadn't been able to do since turning it off for the reboot mentioned in *Edit* and *Edit2* segments. I came to the conclusion of, after using ls and then ls on each printed partition to find the linux installation, that my linux install from the SSD was on (hd1, gpt2). On the basis of the uncontrollable circumstance that my very first linux install, dual boot, was on the hard disk and not the SSD, the hard disk drive holds the name /dev/sda and the nvme I believe is /dev/nvme0n1 and the linux install is /dev/nvme0n1p2. With that in mind, I used in GNU GRUB 2.06 to finally try and load the kernel… with help from this answered question, specifically the most voted answer by Saber, [I can't get out of grub + you need to load the kernel first](https://askubuntu.com/questions/978886/i-cant-get-out-of-grub-you-need-to-load-the-kernel-first)

```
linux (hd1,gpt2)/boot/vm
```

(I pressed tab which gave a code). Then I typed `root=/dev/nvme0n1p2` after a space in the printed code, and to end my downward staircase of despair I logged back in.

Then, as per the rest of the answer I ran the command `sudo update-grub`. That worked, however, the next command, `grub-install /dev/nvme0n1`, which is specific to my device, did not. So I used the boot-repair program as mentioned at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair.

This solved the problem inadverdently created in *Edit* and *Edit2* sections of this post.

My hard disk drive now, as seen in gparted, had a fat32 partition for uefi and a partition of unknown format; I have formatted it to ext4 and it can be detected, but that brings me to yhe initial problem: it is still read-only. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got back access.

I formatted the hard drive (Quick,slow mode was unnecessary) in Disks to ext4. Then the hard drive was r/w again, as checked using `$ ls -l /dev/sda1` as the hard drive partition was now sda1. It gave

```
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 1 Dec  6 12:12 /dev/sda1
```

Which indicated r/w status. Then I launched Nautilus file manager  `$ nautilus` from terminal as it seems that is the file manager on my system. There I changed permissions for ownership to my user (Ratconned if my username were that, for example) and permissions and permission to create and delete files. For enclosed files for folders I changed owner and group permissions to create and delete files and for files I changed owner and group permmissions to read-write (unsure of the implications of giving group permission at this time but I am the only one who uses this laptop).